# Apache Beam Dataflow Bigquery Streming insertions out of memory error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm intermittently getting out-of-memory issues on the dataflow job when inserting the data into Bigauqery using Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.29.0.

Here is the stack trace

```
    Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:982)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1022)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.flushRows(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:375)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.access$800(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:69)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite$BatchAndInsertElements.finishBundle(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:271)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1343)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:129)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:724)
        com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.writeContentToOutputStream(NetHttpRequest.java:188)
        com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:117)
        com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.lambda$insertAll$1(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:906)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$BoundedExecutorService$SemaphoreCallable.call(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1492)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I tried increasing the worker node size still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Are you working with Batch or Streaming ? Could you consider using the last version of beam ? What machine-type are you using ?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet, in order to see if an operation is costly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend you to upgrade your `Beam` version to 2.42.0 (latest).

Also check if you have some aggregation like `groupBy` or `groupByKey` that are costly in memory inside a worker.

You can also use `Dataflow` `prime`, that is the last execution engine for `Dataflow` and allows to prevent errors like `outOfMemory` in a worker with vertical autoscaling :

[dataflow prime](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/enable-dataflow-prime)

`Dataflow` `prime` can be enabled with a program argument, example for `Beam` `Java` :

```
--dataflowServiceOptions=enable_prime
```

`Dataflow` `prime` helps in this case, but you have to check and optimize your job if needed and avoid costly operations if it's possible (memory leaks, useless aggregation, costly serialization...)

Answer (score 0):

`OutOfMemory` issues can be very tough to debug because the symptom you see may be totally unrelated to the sources of memory pressure. So your pipeline is throwing this when trying to create a thread in the `insertAll` method, but it's possible that most of your memory usage is coming from some other part of your pipeline.

There's some in-depth advice on debugging memory issues at https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/dataflow-debug-oom-conditions

If the memory pressure is coming from BigQueryIO, take a look at various config options such as [maxStreamingRowsToBatch](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/abb932e97ab2e87ec1eaf0dbf9f177b949a35751/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryOptions.java#L64).